# Scoring Model giving reversed results using logistic regression

Tags: pivot, regression, logistic-regression, factors, scoring

I am trying to implement a scoring model following the link https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/376828_032c59adbc984b0ab892ce0026370352.html#1_introduction.
Post the entire implementation though, When I create pivot with my generated scores and the original labels, the average scores for "good' labels is significantly lower than the ones for " high" labels.
Hence, my problem can be oversimplified to why would logistic regression give reversed probabilities for 0-1 target variable( In my model I am using 0 for bad and 1 for good).

Any suggestions and solutions would be welcome.